# implement didUpdateLocations delegate method of CLLocationManager in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have implemented `-(void)localnotification` in DashboardController.m.Now I want to access `localnotification` and implement `didUpdateLocations` delegate methods into settingsController.m class. My approach is so far:

DashBoardViewController.h

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@class AppDelegate;
@interface DashBoardViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>{

    AppDelegate *appDel;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic,retain) CLLocation *current;

-(void)localnotification;
@end
```

DashBoardViewController.m

```
#import "DashBoardViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface DashBoardViewController ()
@end 
@implementation DashBoardViewController

@synthesize current,locationManager;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appDel = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [self localnotification];
}

-(void)localnotification{ 
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

Now in SettingController.m I am accessing like this:

```
@implementation SettingsViewController
DashBoardViewController *dash;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appDel = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    dash=[[DashBoardViewController alloc] init];
    [dash localnotification];
    NSArray *locations;
    [self locationManager:appDel.locationManager didUpdateLocations:locations];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    //location 1
    CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:appDel.latVal longitude:appDel.longVal];

    //location 2
    CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:appDel.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude longitude:appDel.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude ];

    appDel.latVal = appDel.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude; //Latitute of the location
    appDel.longVal = appDel.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude; //Longitude of the location

    //Difference between location 1 & location 2
    CLLocationDistance dist = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
    NSLog(@"Difference from Settings: %ld",lroundf(dist));
    NSLog(@"Last Location's Object Settings: %@",[locations lastObject]);
}
```

But [locations lastObject] is returning null in the settingsController class. In view Controller class I don't have to define the **locations** array but in settings class as I only accessing **localnotification** method I have declare the locations array otherwise it gives error. What should I pass

```
[self locationManager:appDel.locationManager didUpdateLocations:?];
```

Comment: do you getting this issue only in iOS 8 ?

Comment: My development target is 7.1. I don't understand, in DashBoardViewController where I implemented both methods its working perfectly. But In SettingController where I called the localnotification and didUpdateLocations method if I didn't declare `locations` array its giving error.

Comment: If its already working on 1 page & not working on other than there could be something you missing. Try to implement again in the page where its not working

Comment: Can you look once again just the `settingsController` class's code?. Is it the proper way to call the delegate method or should I have to call delegate method?. I mean in `dashboardviewconroller` class I don't even have to call the `didUpdateLocations` method in viewDidLoad but in setting conntoller If I don't call the didUpdateLocations method then its not calling automatically.

Comment: its not at all proper way

Comment: @cyberlobe: can you show me the proper way please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the best way to use Location manager in multiple view controllers:

in **AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager * locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;
```

in **AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
        currentLocation_ = [[CLLocation alloc] init];
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    currentLocation_ = newLocation;
}
```

Now in DashBoardViewController & SettingsViewController

**@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *currentLocation;**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        currentLocation_ = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:appDelegate.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:appDelegate.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    }
}
```

**Note:**
Its for an example, You can improve it as per your need.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Ok I will implemnt this!

Comment: how to set the location address string from appdelegate to dashboardcontroller UILabel without using a NSTimer in dashboardcontroller ?

Comment: @Poles as cyberlobe answer here you should instead always use the singleton pattern for this sort of thing.use the AppDelegate as it’s faster to implement.  If I’m building a serious application, I would choose the singleton pattern.